# Android Studio facing a issue to run a fresh new app

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

I just create a new flutter application I installed android studio as i am beginner but i get these issue.
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO KE5k in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: any `flutter doctor -v` issue found?

Comment: [X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).


! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Connect to a nice internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

seems like it just needs to download stuff check your internet connection . if your country is banned by google be sure to use a good secure vpn

Comment: Internet is working good and google is also not banned

Comment: @AwaisAli use a good vpn just to be sure